# Best way for mapping array of strings

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, string, algorithm

I faced with the next task: I have an array of strings which stands for location names, for instance ["Rome", "Paris", "Kyiv", "Barcelona"], and I have to add a comma after each element except the last one. So, what is the best way to do so? Thanks for your help.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Share your code and explain where exactly you got stuck.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this -

```
["Rome", "Paris", "Kyiv", "Barcelona"].joined(separator: ", ")
```

Answer (score 0):

That's in java but the idea is to start after the first element and then adding commas behind it.

```
if (arrayListWords.length >= 1) {
System.out.print(arrayListWords[0]);
}

// note that i starts at 1, since we already printed the element at index 0
for (int i = 1; i < arrayListWords.length, i++) { 
 System.out.print(", " + arrayListWords[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a real app, present lists using

```
ListFormatter().string(from:)
```